# Qt application crash when trying to delete Qimage Format_RGB888

Tags: qt, crash, qimage, heap-corruption

I get a *"HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: After normal block ... CRT detected that the application  wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."* when variable `test` gets destroyed.
If I change the image size, the crash does not occur, I'm thinking it has something to do with memory alignment, but I cannot figure out what.

I am using the official Qt builds for MSVC 2017 64bit

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QImage>

QImage foo(int width, int height)
{
    QImage retVal(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) // read each line of the image
    {
        QRgb *lineBuf = reinterpret_cast<QRgb *>(retVal.scanLine(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            lineBuf[j] = qRgb(0,0,0);
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    {
        QImage test = foo(5,5);
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `QRgb` is 32 bits whereas `QImage::Format_RGB888` is 24 bits so you're probably writing off the end of the data resulting in undefined behaviour.

Comment: i cant reproduce it; can you share your build env?

Comment: @G.M. Yes that seems to be the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GM suggested in the comment above, the problem is that QRgb is a 32bit construct.
I've changed the code replacing QRgb with a custom RGB struct

```
struct RGB {
   uint8_t r;
   uint8_t g;
   uint8_t b;
};

QImage foo(int width, int height)
{
    QImage retVal(width, height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) // read each line of the image
    {
        RGB *lineBuf = reinterpret_cast<RGB *>(retVal.scanLine(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
        {
            RGB tmp;
            //.... do stuff with tmp
            lineBuf[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    {
        QImage test = foo(5,5);
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```